# UISearchDisplayController and custom UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to change UITextField inside UISearchBar by subclass of UISearchBar. But when edit in UISearchDisplayController's UISearchBar, the field doesn't change the size which i set in **:layoutSubView** method.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    UISearchBar *searchBar = yourSearchController.searchBar;
    UITextField *searchField;
    for(int i = 0; i < [searchBar.subviews count]; i++) {
    if([[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        searchField = [searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
if(!(searchField == nil))
    searchField.frame = CGRectMake(4, 5, 290, 30);
```

Good Luck.

Comment: well, yes this is what I found and already implemented, my problem is when the USearchBar is resized when editing.